# Cassandra, DataStax OpsCenter Community not starting. Windows 7

Tags: windows, cassandra, datastax

I can't seem to get the OptCenter running.

If I try to run cassandra-cli.bat manually from the command line I get the error. "Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give more details?  What version of OpsCenter are you using?  What Operating System version?

Comment: Humm... I probably need to take down this post. I ditched windows and ended up installing Cassandra on a lamp stack.